# поиск по таблице mySQL в php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, таблицы

У меня есть в таблице две колонки que и ans и 3 строки. Мне нужно в колонке que найти нужное мне значение, после чего справа в той же строке, в которой мы нашли нужное нам значение узнать значение ans.

Comment: Ну и что __конкретно__ у вас не получается?

Comment: найти значение ans, которое находится на строке с нужным мне значением que

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете это сделать вот так:

```
select ans from таблица_с_2мя_колонками where que = нужному_значению
```

Comment: Спасибо, не подскажите какой командой можно вывести значение ans на страницу как здесь https://www.google.com/robots.txt ? Просто ноль в php.